# what is 1.0 in the statement "import bb.cascades 1.0"

Tags: qml, blackberry-10

I want to know the significance of 1.0 in `import bb.cascades 1.0` in `main.qml` file in BB10 app development project.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 1.0 is the version number.

At the moment there is only version 1.0 of the bb.cascades library.  The purpose of this would be for future compatibility, so that if a phone has a new bb10 OS with any major changes to the cascades library your app will still work as it tells the OS it's built for version 1.0.